# How to add periodic task in compute function of dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I want to send log to server periodically after 30 sec.
For performance i want to use different thread by using compute function.
But Timer is not working in compute.
Any suggestions to do task in different threads periodically in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use an [`Isolate`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html) directly. It's what `compute` does under the hood.

However, I don't think sending information to a server would block your UI thread too much.

On top of that, if you're using app state to determine the log message I would just keep it in the main `Isolate`.

I would probably wrap the (Material|Widget|Cupertino)App in a StatefulWidget and add a `Timer.periodic` in the `initState`.

You also have to note communicating with an `Isolate` means your message has to be copied to its memory. While sending an HTTP Request to a server is usually `async` and non-ui-blocking.